# Jdbc driver error : jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver

Tags: mysql, jdbc, tomcat6, mysql-connector

I am getting the below error when i am trying to connect to my database.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:     java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap
at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.<clinit>(NonRegisteringDriver.java:83)
at java.lang.Class.initializeClass(libgcj.so.7rh)
at java.lang.Class.initializeClass(libgcj.so.7rh)
at java.lang.Class.forName(libgcj.so.7rh)
at java.lang.Class.forName(libgcj.so.7rh)
at test.main(test.java:14)
```

Information :

Platform : RHEL 5
Java : jdk1.6.0_45
jdbc connector : mysql-connector-java-5.1.26-bin.jar
Sever: Tomcat 6

I have placed the jdbc connector inside usr/share/java/ Directory.
and my program to test the connection is placed in the root folder.

I have set the CLASSPATH to point to the connector using EXPORT command.
and I am using javac filename.java command to compile & java filename to run it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have installed the old version of mysql connector which was compatible with RHEL5
and now its working fine.
Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

A JDBC driver doesn't need to be installed or configured. You download the jar, add it to the runtime classpath of your application, and you're done:

```
java -cp someJar.jar:someDirectory:theMySQLJdbcDriver.jar com.foo.bar.Main
```

Comment: I am still getting this error ...com.mysql.jdbc.Driver not found in gnu.gcj.run

Comment: Edit you question. Explain recesely where you placed the driver jar, where you are when executing your app, and which command you execute.

Comment: Edit you question. Explain precisely where you placed the driver jar, where you are when executing your app, and which command you execute.